# Matlab stateflow else transition

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

I have a Stateflow with state that handles the following pseudo code:

```
if input1==1 then
  new_state=state2;
else if input==2 then
  new_state=state3;
else
  new_state=error_state;
end if;
```

How to model the else in Stateflow? Currently I'm using [~(input==1 || input==2)], but when I have 10 transitions it becomes very nasty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the following type of construct.  From `state_one` the decision about where to move next is made successively at each `junction`.

[image]